# Working around "ModuleNotFoundError: ...'__main__' is not a package" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a project running on a server with the structure

```
proj
    __init__.py
    module_a.py
    module_b.py
    main.py
```

And in the header of main.py, I import from other modules with the format

```
from .module_a import func1
from .module_b import func2
```

This runs fine on the server, but when I'm testing things on my local machine it raises the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.module_a'; '__main__' is not a package
```

There have been a lot of questions asked regarding this error and the accepted solution is almost always to replace the import statement with

```
from proj.module_a import func1
```

Is there something I can do to configure my local environment to allow this type of syntax without having a completely different set of import statements depending on whether the code is running locally or remotely?

Comment: What is the structure in your local environment? How are you testing exactly, I mean do you start execution from a different entry point when testing locally, compared to server execution?

Comment: When I run it locally I use main.py as the entry point, whereas on the server a function is imported from main.py as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your imports relative, without using the package full path, so that you have the flexibility of renaming it as you wish, like in

```
from .module_a import func1
```

Then in your local environment, change your current dir to the `proj` parent folder and run:

```
python -m proj.main
```

An alternative would be to rename `main.py` to `__main__.py` and then just writing

```
python -m proj
```

will do. But that may affect the behaviour on the server if you copy the files as is.

Packages are usually to be imported. This is a common problem when we start running from arbitrary scripts located inside the package (in this case `main.py`). If the package is simply imported from outside, everything works.