# How to make an module inside a package also executable on the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

In Python 2 we had a pattern where modules also could be directly executed to run unit tests, for debugging etc.

So eg i had animals/_generic.py animals/birds.py and animals/fish.py (and obviously **init**.py).

fish.py might look like this:

```
import _generic 
…
if __name__ = ‘__main__’:
    # do some obscure fishy thing
```

In some hypotetical web application I could import animals.fish. But I could also do on the Shell:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python animals/fish.py
```

to execute some obscure fishy functionality (or doctests).

But if I change to modern relative imports

```
from . import _generic
```

direct execution from the command line, execution is impossible because fish.py is not inside a Package.

Is there a pattern I am missing to implement the option of occasional direct execution with packages and relative imports?

Comment: Try `python -m animals.fish`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824215/working-around-modulenotfounderror-main-is-not-a-package-error/64866577#64866577)

Comment: Great! Works even with argparse: `python -m components.orders.processor --help`